# Internal build error in Flash Builder

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I am getting Internal build error in Flash Builder.
When I go to the Problems Editor, it says that I can find more details in the error log.

[image]

What does Adobe mean by referring me to the error log? Where I can find it?

Answer (score 5):

This error appears at me sometimes, I never found the real reason...

Sometimes, if I save a file during the build process, something goes wrong and I get the error...

go to `Project -> Clean Project`, and it should disappear....

Comment: This is the correct answer for the "Internal Build Error" as well as when you suddenly get errors saying images are not embedding and when an error appears that includes a class name suffixed with "_HELPER". Clean Project should clear up all of those

Comment: There's an Error View (Window -> Show View -> General -> Error Log) that should contain some info. Another place is a log file located typically under your Flash Builder/Eclipse installation directory. It's a plain text file which includes a dump of java stack, which does not provide any help most of the times. What @Marcx told you works quite well. Sometimes you need to restart Flash Builder though.